# Inheriting DataGridView and changing rows type

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've a control named UIGrid which is inherited from DataGridView
Now, I want to change the Rows property type from DataGridViewRowCollection to UIGridRowCollection
I've overloaded the Rows property to return my type but it's not working as i want
I need that when i set a DataSource for the grid, It adds UIGridRow objects instead of DataGridViewRow
How can i make that possible ???
NOTE: The control is used in a solution with 45 project, So i can't change to a third-party solution

Here is a sample code:

```
Public Class UIGrid : Inherits DataGridView
  Private _Rows As UIGridRowCollection
  Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Rows As UIGridRowCollection
    Get
      If _Rows Is Nothing Then
        _Rows = New UIGridRowCollection(Me)
      End If
      Return _Rows
    End Get
  End Property
End Class

Public Class UIGridRow : Inherits DataGridViewRow
  Public Property ChildControl As Control
End Class

Public Class UIGridRowCollection : Inherits DataGridViewRowCollection
  Public Sub New(grid As UIGrid)
    MyBase.New(CType(grid, DataGridView))
  End Sub

  Public Overloads Function Add(row As UIGridRow) As Integer
    Return MyBase.Add(row)
  End Function
End Class
```

Now, When i try to use the UIGrid control and add rows to it, I face the error:
Row index provided is out of range.
sample code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.UiGrid1.Columns.Add("Id", "Id")
    Me.UiGrid1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name")
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim row As New UIGridRow
        row.CreateCells(Me.UiGrid1)
        row.Cells(0).Value = i
        row.Cells(1).Value = "Employee " & i.ToString
        Me.UiGrid1.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
End Sub
```

And when i set the DataSource property for the grid, The Rows property still counts 0, It seems that the grid doesn't use the overloaded Rows property

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        dt.Rows.Add(i, "Name " & i)
    Next
    Me.UiGrid1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

I need that when i use DataSource property, The grid uses the overloaded Rows property and adds rows of type UIGridRow instead of DataGridViewRow

Answer (score 0):

I am actually facing same problem ... i solved like this (not elegant maybe) ...
Not sure will work with datasource property - not tested

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class myGrid : Inherits DataGridView
    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property MyRows As List(Of UIGridRow)
        Get
            Dim oLst As New List(Of UIGridRow)
            For Each ORow As DataGridViewRow In MyBase.Rows
                oLst.Add(CType(ORow, UIGridRow))
            Next
            MyRows = oLst
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property MySelectedRows As List(Of UIGridRow)
        Get
            Dim oLst As New List(Of UIGridRow)
            For Each oRow As DataGridViewRow In MyBase.SelectedRows
                oLst.Add(CType(oRow, UIGridRow))
            Next
            MySelectedRows = oLst
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Class UIGridRow : Inherits DataGridViewRow
        Public Property Checked As Boolean
    End Class
    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property CurrentRow As UIGridRow
        Get
            Return CType(MyBase.CurrentRow, UIGridRow)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

and on test form:

```
Imports myGrid.myGrid
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     MyBase.Load
        MyGrid1.Columns.Add("Id", "Id")
        MyGrid1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name")
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            Dim row As New myGrid.myGrid.UIGridRow
            row.CreateCells(MyGrid1)
            row.Cells(0).Value = i
            row.Cells(1).Value = "Employee " & i.ToString
            row.Checked = (i < 5)
            MyGrid1.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub MyGrid1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)    Handles MyGrid1.SelectionChanged
        Debug.Print(CStr(MyGrid1.MyRows(MyGrid1.CurrentRow.Index).Checked))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
        For Each oRow As UIGridRow In MyGrid1.MySelectedRows
            oRow.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```